# Modeling the evolution of determinants to support of Quebec indepedence

Tags: r, time-series, bayesian, modeling

I'm working on an political science article where we want to study the evolution of what determines the support to Quebec independence from Canada. We have survey data from 1974 to 2023. More concretely, we want to see the evolution of the force of the association between each IV (language, age, education, vote intention, etc.) and the DV across the years.

The first way of doing this that came to mind was to do separate regression models for each year and simply plot the regression coefficients and their confidence intervals through each model. While this method is quick and simple, I have identified to major concerns: 1. it is heavily dependent on the quality of the survey samples and 2. we lose information from year to year (for example, the coefficient of the language variable from 1974 does not inform the coefficient of the language variable from 1980).

So I am looking for a method which will generate different coefficients for each IV for each year while taking into account the former coefficients of this IV. I think the data is too big and that there are too many terms to do hierarchical models.

I possess strong programming skills and a capacity for learning, which makes me open to exploring more advanced statistical methods if they prove to be the most suitable for my research design. However, before committing to a potentially demanding learning process, I am seeking validation to ensure that the effort is well-directed. I have come across Bayesian structural time series as a promising approach at first glance, but I want to be certain that it is the right choice for this particular research context.

I don't have the data yet, but here is a code excerpt to simulate what the data will look like on a subset of variables.

```r
library(dplyr)

# Set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

# Define survey years, probabilities, and number of observations
survey_years <- c(1974, 1980, 1984, 1988, 1993, 1997, 2000, 2004, 2006, 2008,  
    2011, 2015, 2019, 2021, 2022, 2023)
probs <- c(0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.6, 0.475, 0.475, 0.5, 0.45, 0.4, 0.35, 
    0.3, 0.3, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33)
ns <- c(1500, 1500, 1500, 1500, 1500, 1500, 1500, 1500, 1500, 1500, 2000, 
    6000, 6000, 10000, 10000, 1500)

# Create dataset
data <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:length(survey_years)) {
  year_data <- data.frame(
    survey_year = rep(survey_years[i], ns[i]),
    support_sovereignty = rbinom(ns[i], 1, probs[i])
  )
  data <- rbind(data, year_data)
}

# Factorize the year variable
data$survey_year <- factor(data$survey_year)

# Add other variables (simplified example)
data <- data %>%
  mutate(
    gender = sample(c("male", "female"), n(), replace = TRUE, 
                    prob = c(0.5, 0.5)),
    language = sample(c("french", "other"), n(), replace = TRUE, 
                      prob = c(0.7, 0.3)),
    education = as.vector(scale(sample(1:5, n(), replace = TRUE))),
    income = as.vector(scale(runif(n(), min = 30000, max = 100000))),
    region = sample(c("montreal", "suburban_montreal", "quebec_city", 
              "suburban_quebec_city", "other_region"), 
                    n(), replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.3, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2))
  )

# Add effects of variables
for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
  # language
  if (data$language[i] == "french") {
data$support_sovereignty[i] <- rbinom(1, 1, min(1, probs[data$survey_year[i] == survey_years] + 0.25))
  }
  
  # middle income
  if (data$income[i] >= -1 && data$income[i] <= 1) {
    data$support_sovereignty[i] <- rbinom(1, 1, min(1, probs[data$survey_year[i] == survey_years] + 0.1))
  }
  
  # region
  if (data$region[i] == "montreal") {
data$support_sovereignty[i] <- rbinom(1, 1, 
           max(0, probs[data$survey_year[i] == survey_years] - 0.1))
  } else if (data$region[i] == "other_region") {
    data$support_sovereignty[i] <- rbinom(1, 1, 
           min(1, probs[data$survey_year[i] == survey_years] + 0.2))
  }
}
```

I've been suggested to do something like this:

```r
model <- glmer(
  support_sovereignty ~ gender + language + education + income + 
                        (1 + region | survey_year),
  data = data,
  family = binomial()
)
```

And repeat for each IV. Would it be a good solution?